# Python automate click on "SomeProgram has sopped working" dialog

Tags: python, windows, automation

I have a python automated test script which launches an windows executable file using a wide range of parameters. Occasionally, this will cause the application to immediately crash and displays the "this program has stopped working" dialog. When this happens I need to close that dialog to move on with other tests.

How would I go about:

1. Detect that the "ExampleProgram has stopped working" window has appeared
2. Automatically click the "X" to close the dialog upon detection
   [image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging around I found the best way to achieve this is to poll the process table every five seconds to find the Windows Error Reporter, and kill the process if it is found:

```
import psutil, os    
if "DWWIN.EXE" in (p.name() for p in psutil.process_iter()):
    os.system("taskkill /F /IM DWWIN.EXE")
```

Answer (score 1):

Not fully sure if it will work, but you could try this approach:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

program = 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office 15\\root\\office15\\EXCEL.EXE'
parameters = ['/e']

process = Popen([program, parameters], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
(out, err) = process.communicate()

if process.returncode == 0:
    print('Program has closed normally')
else:
    print('Program terminated unexpectedly with exit code {}'.format(process.returncode))
```